# Почему программа завершается, не дожидаясь выполнения потока?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Вот простой пример:

```
import threading as TH
import time

def make():
    print("RUN");
    time.sleep(2);
    print("END");

t = TH.Thread(target=make);
t.daemon = True;
t.start();
```

вывод:

```
RUN
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Как я понял, программа должна работать в фоне, но почему не печатается "`END`"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Поведение отличается от ожидаемого потому, что Вы не ждёте завершения потока. Ваша программа сейчас запускает поток, а затем прекращает свою работу. Поток "убивается", не успев выполниться полностью. Поставьте после запуска команду ожидания завершения:

```
t.join()
```

P.S. В *Python* точка с запятой в конце строки не нужна.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: поток убивается *только из-за того*, что он является демоном. Обычный поток не убивается принудительно при завершении основного.

Comment: @cmd Думаю, Вам стоит принять ответ Timofey Bondarev, он гораздо более обстоятельный и точный.

Answer (score 7):

Для начала небольшое отступление, которое стоит держать в голове при использовании потоков на Python:

> In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once <...> However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

Перевод:
Из-за GIL в CPython в каждый момент времени только один поток может исполнять Python код. Тем не менее, многопоточность всё ещё подходит, если вы планируете запускать множество задач, связанных с вводом-выводом.

Это я к тому, что стоит подумать об использовании процессов для параллелизации вычислений, если ваши потоки не занимаются чтением/записью.

---

Далее по коду. Вы создаёте поток демон. [Программа завершается в тот момент, когда не осталось ни одного потока, не являющегося демоном](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left.  <...>
>   Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly.

Если не устанавливать свойство `daemon` в `True`, то программа завершится не раньше, чем завершатся все созданные вспомогательные потоки:

```
import threading
import time


def make():
    print("RUN")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("END")


t = threading.Thread(target=make)
t.start()
```

Эта программа выведет и RUN, и END даже без использования метода [`t.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join), так как по умолчанию создаётся обычный поток, а не демон.

---

С потоками-демонами всё сложнее. Если вам необходимо дожидаться завершения некоторых потоков, тогда, возможно, они не должны быть демонами.
Если же нужно дождаться завершения демона, то можно использовать метод `join`, как уже предлагалось ранее. Это работает с любым типом потока. Операция `join` блокирует поток, что не даёт программе завершиться раньше, чем завершит свою работу поток-демон.

- Документация по свойству [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) потока
- Документация по методу [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) потока

Comment: не нужно упоминать GIL в вопросах, связанных с потоками, где GIL не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме. И так я вижу люди, которые *ничего* не знают о параллельном программировании, на любые проблемы с кодом, отвечают что GIL виноват (что неверно в большинстве случаев -- как и в данном случае -- поток умрёт, есть GIL или нет).

Answer (score 5):

Сперва нужно знать, что каждое приложение имеет **привилегированный главный поток** `Main`, который создается и стартует одновременно с началом приложения, и оканчивается с окончанием выполнения последнего оператора. 
Но когда же пользователь создает свой поток-демон, поток начинает свою работу параллельно потоку `Main`, т.е поток главный `Main` не ждет пока пользовательский поток закончит свою работу, если так было бы, то не было смысла в потоках, ведь исчезла бы параллельность. Но бывают такие случаи, когда требуется ожидать, когда поток-демон завершит свою работу, как в твоем случаи, для этого и существует метод `join()`.

Кстати, ты так и не увидел `END`, лишь потому что основному потоку плевать окончил ли работу поток-демон или же нет.

А вообще, все придет со временем

Comment: У вас пара неточностей в ответе. Главный поток **может** завершиться до завершения всех потоков приложения. Завершение программы принудительно завершает только потоки-демоны, так что если есть поток, не являющийся демоном, и он ещё не завершился, программа будет его дожидаться и не завершится раньше его.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev да, точно)) Сейчас исправим